# Vue: Set focus to dynamic input box

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form where user can fill an email address and click a plus button against it to create a new one. These input boxes are generated by iterating over an array. When user clicks on the + icon, a new entry is pushed to this array.

Now the new text box is generating fine but I want the cursor to be focused in this one.

[image]

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 8):

as @ramakant-mishra told you must use `this.$refs`, but you need to add ref attribute dynamically on your input element also. let me show you:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    emails:[]
  },
  methods: {
    add: function (e) {
      let j = this.emails.push("")
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs[`email${j - 1}`][0].focus()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(email, i) in emails" :key="i">
    <input v-model="email" :ref="`email${i}`" />
  </div>
  <button @click="add">add</button>
</div>
```

just don't forget to use $nextTick because the new element is not rendered yet on template

Answer (score 4):

They key is to set `ref` on all your `input`s to the same string like this:

```
<input type="text" ref="myInputs"/>
```

Then you will have access to an array called `this.$refs.myInputs` inside an event handler.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {
      emails: []
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    addEmail() {
      this.emails.push('whatever');
      this.$nextTick(() => {
          const lastIdx = this.emails.length - 1;
          this.$refs.myInputs[lastIdx].focus();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="button" @click="addEmail()" value="Add Email"/>
  <div v-for="(email, index) in emails" :key="index">
    <input ref="myInputs" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that below you must put the call to `focus()` inside a `nextTick()` in order to give Vue a chance to actually render the email you just added to the list.